# Setting custom accessoryView make a margin to contentView from right side

Tags: uitableview, ios9, margin, iphone-6-plus, accessoryview

When I have set accessoryView I get a margin from right side contentView in 15px (or 20px if scale equal 3). I tried remove this gap, but without result. 
Somebody have a idea what is it? how remove this or reliably calculate size of gap?

[image]

On screenshot:
1) custom accessoryView zero size
2) default accessoryType